# Axios Get an express session returns undefined, Yet POSTMAN returns the correct data

Tags: reactjs, express, session, axios

I'm having a problem trying to get information from a server session.
I have a login function that puts the user's info into the server session.

I wrote a test function to see if it works:

```
router.post('/userLogged', async(request, response) => {
if (request.session.user === undefined) {
    response.status(401).send('Not Allowed')
    return;
}
response.json(request.session.user);
```

})

When I run this function with POSTMAN it works great and returns the session data.

But when I try to call this with Axios on the Client side:

```
private userLogged = async()=>{
    try{
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
        const response = await axios.post(`${url}/userLogged`,{withCredentials: true});
        console.log(response)
    }catch(err){
        alert(err.message)
    }
}
```

I always get Undefined, What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Following this issue here (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/587), it seems that you may be able to solve this by using axios' default settings instead.

Otherwise, some people have also advised making sure that the backend is using CORS and the issue may be resolved with:

> it's not an issue with axios i just made it work on the latest version, I was using express cors so i simply added credentials: true, origin: http://yourdomain:3000. This won't work on localhost you have to point your localhost into some fake domain and have all your apps run on that domain

Answer (score 0):

postman does not apply CROS domain check, not like the browser

Comment: Ok, But once I add withCredentials : true - I get the following CORS error:
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'